# How to disable irritating beeping sound in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

sometimes I run grep (aka select-string) that has string that occurs too often, then PowerShell goes crazy, sometimes I manage to kill it with Ctrl+C, but even then I have to endure irritating beeping sound for 30 + seconds... can this be disabled also without killing terminal where it is running?

Comment: `sc config beep start= disabled` `sc stop beep` ?

Comment: @STTR: Make that `sc.exe`, since `sc` in PowerShell is an alias for `Set-Content`. Read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838671 for more details. Make this in to an answer.

Comment: The term 'sc.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 8):

Open your PowerShell profile, or type:

```
if (!(Test-Path $profile)) {New-Item -Type File -Path $profile -Force}
```

to make a profile if one doesn't exist.

Then add `Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None` to the profile to turn the sound off.

(that sound drives my dog insane, it was sapping my will to live)

Answer (score 2):

This powershell is the SC equivalent that was already answered.

```
Get-Service Beep | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `Set-Service beep -StartupType Disabled` if you are only looking to disable the service.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the window menu bar, select 'Settings', then on the left click on the 'Windows PowerShell' profile, on the right and at the bottom choose 'Advanced', then unclick all the checkboxes for the 'Bell Notification' style.

PowerShell Appearance Settings

[image]