# Disable PowerShell beep on backspace

Tags: powershell

This feature seems to have been added in PowerShell version 5.1, as I don't find it on my laptop still running 5.0.

When pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in PowerShell, it will emit a 'beep' sound if there is no (more) text to delete. This is quite annoying if you accidentally hold down the key too long, as the sound will keep going for a short while after you release it.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/573294/how-to-disable-iritating-beeping-sound-in-powershell) Super User question which suggests to disable the Beep service, which does work, but I would like to still be able to use beeps in scripts.

How do I disable the "beep on backspace" sound without disabling beeps completely?

Comment: `Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None`

Comment: @PetSerAl That works, but I have to set it every time I open a new PowerShell window. Is there any way to make the setting stick?

Comment: [`Get-Help about_Profiles`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847857.aspx)

Comment: @FastEthernet Add it to your [PowerShell Profile File](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_profile_ps1.htm)

Comment: @PetSerAl Please post an answer.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The beep is provided by the `PSReadline` module, which shipped with Windows 10. You need to change the `PSReadline` option to disable the bell:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None
```

If you want this change for all future PowerShell sessions, then you need to add this command to your [PowerShell profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Profiles). For example, to set the option for "Current User, Current Host" (`$Profile`):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
if (!(Test-Path -Path "$Profile")) {New-Item -ItemType File -Path "$Profile" -Force}
Add-Content -Value "Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None" -Path "$Profile"
```

The first line allows your profile run a startup script when PowerShell opens ([About Execution Policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies)). The second line tests to see if you already have a startup script defined for "Current User, Current Host". The third line adds the bell option to your startup script.

Comment: @Odys no - that's the same way you'd have to do it in Bash/ZSH or any Unix shell too.

Comment: this requires running scripts; disabled by default (win10)

Answer (score 21):

A more permanent solution that extends [@PetSerAl](https://superuser.com/a/1113450/95744)'s answer:

1. Run PowerShell as administrator.
2. Execute: `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`. This will allow PowerShell scripts to run on your computer. If you are not sure on what that is do not continue.
3. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` if you are on Windows 10.
4. Create a file named `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.
5. Edit that file and add `Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None`.
6. Open a new PowerShell console and you should not hear the beep any more.

All (new) PowerShell consoles for all users on your computer are now silent.

This answer is for Windows 10. 
For other versions of Windows, the folder might differ.

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy` may require elevated permissions, so if you want to change this setting for your own user only, you can use it with `-Scope CurrentUser` argument.

Comment: @ the down-voter, care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

An adaptation of @Odys' answer using the Bash shell on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (assuming you have it enabled).

1 Open up a command prompt as an administrator, and run

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

2 Type `bash` to start the bash shell

3 Change to the proper directory

```
cd /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
```

4 Make a file named "Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1" and write "Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None" to it

```
echo "Set-PSReadlineOption -BellStyle None" >> Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1
```

Comment: I can't add a file under the given path, which is no surprise because the access rights to the folder don't include write. I tried to modify access rights, but no luck. Did you face a problem like this?

Comment: try `sudo chmod 644 ./Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1` to give yourself privileges. I don't remember my root password, so I can't confirm this works.

Comment: Thank you but chmod can only attempt to change the files access permissions only if the file exists. My problem is that I can't create Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1 under the folder v1.0.
v1.0 (folder) lacks the access right to write on it, therefore I can't create a file under that folder. I tried to change the access rights of v1.0, but apparently chmod has some issues with subsystem. How did you manage to create a file under v1.0?