# How to prevent the delete key from acting like backspace

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

In PowerShell 6.0.1, the out-of-the-box behavior is that when I press <kbd>Delete</kbd> while my caret is not at the end of the line, it deletes the character above the caret, as expected. However, once I delete the last character on the line, it moves the caret back a position. I find this very annoying, because I can no longer just hold <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete until the end of the line. Is there a way to change it so that it behaves the same as when I press <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> - i.e. it does nothing?

[image: delete key]

## Research undertaken:

I saw [Disable PowerShell beep on backspace](https://superuser.com/q/1113429/511640), and thought perhaps there is also a setting for what I want, but after reading [the docs on the PSReadLine cmdlet](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/blob/416ca3e4e3712a732d3bd2c50e4fa2fd1030ceac/docs/Set-PSReadLineOption.md), I saw that there isn't.

I then looked into keybindings, and ran `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler` to check what <kbd>Delete</kbd> is currently assigned to, and then [searched for  `DeleteChar` in the `PSReadLine` codebase](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=deletechar&type=), to see the definition for that function, and to browse around for something similar. I found [DeleteCharOrExit](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/blob/46d232c22ac3f24a95e32d773c594ad306dfc327/PSReadLine/BasicEditing.cs#L207), and ran `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Delete -Function  DeleteCharOrExit` which doesn't exit the "delete" process - as I assumed from the unclear doc comment - it exits the PowerShell console process...

I also found https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/486, which suggests it has been fixed, but clearly not...

Maybe I need to inject some custom keybinding code like https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/blob/46d232c22ac3f24a95e32d773c594ad306dfc327/PSReadLine/SamplePSReadLineProfile.ps1#L257-L291?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that PowerShell Core 6.0.1 ships with version 1.2 of the PSReadLine module, as seen by `Get-Module PSReadLine`, but the fix was in https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta1. Seeing as that release says:

> This is the first release from the repo supporting both PowerShell Core (all platforms) and Windows PowerShell.

I assumed I had that version and didn't check originally.

To get it working with that version, one can use:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Delete `
                             -BriefDescription Delete `
                             -LongDescription "Delete character over the caret" `
                             -ScriptBlock {
        param($key, $arg)

        $line = $null
        $cursor = $null
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref]$line, [ref]$cursor)

        if ($cursor -lt $line.Length)
        {
            [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Delete($cursor, 1)
        }
    }
```

(ideally by placing it in the appropriate profile file so that it is auto-run when PowerShell starts.)

This can also be fixed by upgrading the PSReadLine module, using the instructions at https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/612, which are:

```
Install-Module PSReadLine -RequiredVersion 2.0.0-beta1 -AllowPrerelease -Scope CurrentUser -SkipPublisherCheck
```

Presumably a future release of PowerShell Core will include a fixed version of the PSReadLine module.